# Jenkins local clone repo path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use jenkins to automate some jobs on a local cloned repo.
The cloning of the repo is going well but when i call my script( its a py script) I need the full local cloned repo path.

for example I will call:
python3.exe myscript.py -d ${params.REPO_DIR}
If I will look into the console it will get only a part of the path like /repo/dir/repo name ..not the full path like C:\user\repo etc..
Which is normal assuming I don't know how to get the full path..
Could some one tell me please how I am able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script is in the cloned repo. You can get the current working directory path with `${env.WORKSPACE}` or `$WORKSPACE` depending on where you are executing. Then you can append the relative path of the pythion script to the current working directory location. `${env.WORKSPACE}/${params.REPO_DIR}`